# How to use @model IEnumerable<> and @model <> in the same page (List / Create) MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say i have a class 'Location', and I'm using MVC3 to create a scaffolding list(index.cshtml). The index html page uses @model IEnumerable. If i want to add a new location to the list, i press create, and i end up with a new html page using @model Project.Models.Location.

Instead of going to a new page, i would like to have the create page as a popup using modal in boostrap(twitter). I've tried using partialview without any luck. Whatever i do i get the dictionary error message.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Project.Models.Location]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Project.Models.Location'.

The modal(bootstrap) itself is working when i'm not fetching the partialview. The partialview itself is exactly the same as the generated create(CRUD).

EDIT: I rewrote the whole thing.

**Index:**

```
@model IEnumerable<LoLStats.Models.Location>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)</li>
    </ul>
}

<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Create</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>@Html.Partial("_createLocation")</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_createLocation:**

> @model LoLStats.Models.Location
>
> @{
>       ViewBag.Title = "Create"; }
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
>       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
>       
>           Location
>
> ```
>     <div class="editor-label">
>         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationName)
>     </div>
>     <div class="editor-field">
>         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationName)
>         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationName)
>     </div>
>     <p>
>         <input type="submit" value="Create" />
>     </p>
> </fieldset> }
> ```

Comment: You have spelled Project wrong  'Prosject.Models.Cars'

Comment: Thats not the problem. I didnt have the exact errormessage at hand, so i wrote it. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: Please also post the code you currently have

Answer (score 4):

You could make a view model that has two properties:

- The IEnumerable for the parent view
- A singular object for the modal

Then strongly type both views to the view model and you should be all set.

**Edit**

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
  public IEnumerable<LoLStats.Models.Location> Locations {get; set;}
  public LoLStats.Models.Location Location {get; set;}
}
```

Index:

```
@model myNamespace.MyViewModel
...
@foreach (var item in Model.Locations) {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Locations.LocationName)</li>
    </ul>
...
```

_createLocation:

```
@model myNamespace.MyViewModel
...
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
    </div>
...
```

Hopefully that's enough detail to get you going

Comment: From best practices perspective, try avoiding using `@model IEnumerable<whatever>`, I.E. generic types. Best is to create view model dedicated to this particular view (usually 1 view model per 1 view) and include in it all view needs to display and to postback to your controller.

Comment: Got the same error still @Forty-Two, but ill have another look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

try this in the Index view:

```
   ... <p>@Html.Partial("_createLocation", Model.FirstOrDefault())</p>
```

on the other hand, maybe this will make more sence:

```
   ... <p>@Html.Partial("_createLocation", new LoLStats.Models.Location())</p>
```

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your pop-up would need to have a model defined as `Project.Models.Car` (singular item). After successfully saving the single item you need to update your original list view. Which you can do using jQuery by inserting a new item into the DOM or just by refreshing the page by navigating to the action that gave you the list to begin with.

Comment: Does this still count after i've update my post? Sry about that btw

Comment: My approach and the answer containing the composite ViewModel both achieve the same results in a different manner. There's always 476 ways to skin a cat in MS code :-)

Comment: Personally, I tend to break my UI up to be less coupled. I like having 2 specific views, one for the list and another to edit. Upon saving the new item I redirect back to the List. But that's just me.

Comment: Here's a way to think about it that may or may not influence your decision. Say you have a List of Cars, are your requirements to show all fields for those cars? If so, if adding new fields to edit, will that affect what you have to show in the List? If you're just showing only a few major fields in the List and the Edit view has all fields then you shouldn't have any problem implementing the Composite ViewModel. So do what's best for your requirements :-)