# Can I create a MVC webgrid with a nested IEnumerable in my ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a similar situation as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939551/how-to-use-model-ienumerable-and-model-in-the-same-page-list-create-m). I also wish to put a `@model IEnumerable<>` inside the parent which is a normal @model.

I did the whole thing with the view model combining the two. But now I don't know how to proceed when I wish to implement my webgrid. How should I bind the model to the webgrid, and should I use `@foreach` since I technically don't have an `IEnumerable` model but I do have a `IEnumerable` property of that model?

```
@model MyViewModel

@{
    var myWebGrid = new WebGrid(Model.theIEnumarablePropertyOfMyViewModel);
}

@foreach (var item in Model.theIEnumarablePropertyOfMyViewModel)
{
    @myWebGrid.GetHtml()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) for a good basic explanation of using a WebGrid.

The most important parts that correspond to the code you posted (without the nested IEnumerable):

```
public ActionResult List()
  {
    IEnumerable<Product> model =
      _productService.GetProducts();

    return View(model);
  }

@model IEnumerable<MsdnMvcWebGrid.Domain.Product>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Basic Web Grid";
}
@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@grid.GetHtml()
```

So everything looks fine in your setup, including the nested IEnumerable, except the line that states:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.theIEnumarablePropertyOfMyViewModel){
@myWebGrid.GetHtml()
}
```

You don't need to iterate over the collection again! You already give the collection in the constructor of the `WebGrid` and afterwards you just call it's `GetHtml()` method to render the results. So the above simply becomes:

```
@myWebGrid.GetHtml()
```

Comment: But now in your description where view is IEnumerable I cant use other models if they are not lists, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: The example I showed you is a little more simple. You can just have your more complex ViewModel that has all kinds of properties including especially an IEnumerable for some kind of Type which will be used to populate the WebGrid.

Comment: Your answer steered me in the right direction, now I realize I just need the syntax to assign my webgrid source from a IEnumerable property of my view model. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: You are already there! Take care of creating e new instance of you ViewModel, assign the IEnumerable to a List of objects, in your action controller method return the View with the Model passed into it, return View(viewModel) and don't forget to mark this answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just think of your view model as an declaration of what your model will contain. If you want an IEnumerable on your model its not a @model IEnumerable its just your @models.IEnumerable. It's just typing of the expected object don't get to hung up on whats a "Normal" model.

A normal model just contains exactly what you need in your view, if in this case you think an Ienumerable is what you need just put it on the model.

Talking about IEnumerables why don't you just create a list with strongly typed items that you want to put in your webgrid since list already implements IEnumerable.... ?

Comment: Because my webgrid pulls data from a database and is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: But if its a grid you still have columns that dont change right? or is it supposed to be different items on the same grid with different columns ? What do you mean by dynamic in this case?

Comment: that is correct, the columns don't change, its just the number of rows that change.

Comment: Then you need to look into how a webgrid woorks and how you feed it data. Your question is: "Can I create a MVC webgrid without an Ienumerable model?" and the answer is yes and no, you need to have a model that implements a datastructer that implements IEnumerable OR you can have a model item that is a datastructure that implements IEnumerable.

If you have specific implementation questions bout how to declare and initialize a webgrid i sugesst making a new question.

Mabey a tutorial like this will help you with the basics: http://goo.gl/cruAkS